# How should I phrase this question?

Tags: sentence, phrasing

I have some supplies for my son's classroom. I need to let his teacher know that I have these supplies to give her, and I need to know how she would like me to get them to her. BUT I would like to insist that she tells me what works best for her and her schedule. (It's the absolute least I could do! She's a saint lol)

For some reason I absolutely can not figure out the correct wording.

"Hi Mrs. C--. I have a few things to give you for the classroom! How would you like me to get them to you that is easiest for you?"

- at this point I just feel ridiculous thinking this hard about a 3-4 sentence text message ‍♀️

Comment: We don't usually do this, but you're golden since the business of "BUT I would like to **insist**" did not make it to your writing.

Comment: Hi Mrs. C--. I have a few things to give you for the classroom! Please let me know the best way to get them to you.

Comment: "What would be the most convenient way I could get them to you?"